Trying to recreate openings in a rectangular prism in OpenSCAD
I would like to take this frame with the top and center cutouts/slots but apply it to a new shape I made

Here is the rounder shape

I was able to get the top slot, but I need help producing the center cutout (to the bottom layer) as well as the hovering cube on top. My code includes these components but for some reason they are not showing up.
// Parameters for the rounded rectangular shape
outer_length = 85;          // Length of the rectangle (in mm)
outer_width = 65;           // Width of the rectangle (in mm)
height = 20;                // Total height of the rectangle (in mm)
corner_radius = 10;         // Radius for the rounded corners (in mm)
bottom_thickness = 1;       // Thickness of the solid bottom layer (in mm)
slot_width = 10;            // Width for headband slots (in mm)
slot_depth = 10;             // Depth for headband slots (in mm)
border_height = 10;         // Height of the raised border (in mm)
border_thickness = 1;       // Thickness of the raised border (in mm)

// Create the rounded rectangular shape
module rounded_rect_prism() {
    difference() {
        // Create the outer rounded rectangle
        hull() {
            for (x = [-outer_length/2, outer_length/2]) {
                for (y = [-outer_width/2, outer_width/2]) {
                    translate([x, y, height/2])
                        sphere(r = corner_radius);
                }
            }
        }

        // Create the inner hollow part, ensuring it starts above the solid bottom layer
        translate([0, 0, bottom_thickness+8]) // Start hollow part above the solid bottom layer
            cube([outer_length, outer_width, height - bottom_thickness], center = true);
        
        // Create the top cutout for the headband in the center of the narrow side
        translate([outer_length/2 + border_thickness+3, 0, bottom_thickness + slot_depth/2+10])
            cube([20, border_height + 10, slot_depth + 4], center = true);
       
        // Cutout under the cube
        translate([0, 0, -1])
            cube([slot_width, slot_width, bottom_thickness + 1], center = true);
  }
 }

// The cube
  difference() {
    translate([0, 0, bottom_thickness + slot_depth/2])
      cube([slot_width, slot_width, slot_depth + 2], center = true);
    translate([0, 0, bottom_thickness-1 + slot_depth/2+1])
      cube([slot_width+2, slot_width, slot_depth -2], center = true);
  }
   


// Rotate and translate to flip the shape
rotate([180, 0, 0]) // Rotate the shape 180 degrees
translate([0, 0, -height + bottom_thickness]) // Translate to align the bottom layer with the origin
    rounded_rect_prism();

I really need help with this so anything pointing me in the right direction would be so appreciated! Thank you!

This is essentially the same question as your previous question albeit you are now wanting the cube in the middle, which was there in the first question. I'm in favor of closing one of these questions. You should allow yourself to read into the capabilities of OpenSCAD, it isn't that difficult, you need to add (union()) or cut (difference()) wanted or unwanted parts at the correct position. Note to do that is a specific order.
